# new DateTime is not working properly with the future date

Tags: php, date, strtotime, date-conversion

I am trying to calculate the differences between 2 dates.

The first date is the reservation date, and the second date is the traveler's birthdate. Format of the $tour_day is 15 December, 202X

```
$date1 = new DateTime($bir_day);
$date2 = new DateTime($tour_day);
$interval = $date1->diff($date2);

if($interval->y < 8) {
// error: Adults must be at least 8 years old
 }
```

It works if the reservation date is the current year.

However if the reservation date is 2022 or more, than it cannot calculate correctly because

```
$date2 = new DateTime($tour_day);
```

is always converts as 2021.

```
echo $tour_day;
```

is '15 December, 2023' But

```
echo $date2->format('m-d-y');
```

is '12-15-21' however it must be '12-15-23' (12-15-23 is what I want but it shows 12-15-21)

I do not understand why the future date (next year or more) is not converting correctly but the current year of any date is no problem.

Comment: If you plan to work a lot with dates, you might be interested in using a library such as [Carbon](https://carbon.nesbot.com/) that builds additional features on top of the PHP date/time handling.

Comment: Thank you so much. Actually I am editing the WooCommerce plugin just to make errors if adults and children ages are not correct. @Sudhir Bastakoti solved this problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

that's because your date string is not in proper format as required by [DateTime](https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.construct.php), use [createFromFormat()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php) as:

```
...
$tour_day = "5 December, 2023";
// your format is "Day Month, Year", so use that format as below
$date2 = DateTime::createFromFormat("j F, Y", $tour_day);
echo $date2->format('m-d-y'); // 12-05-23
...
```

Comment: I cannot thank enough.

I was looking for hours and gave up and asked here.

I appreciated.